# Getting undefined error when sending a dropdown to console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am quite new to Nodejs I am trying to use it to access values within a select drop down menu.  The answer found here  : [Get dropdown value using Express in node.js from html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581459/get-dropdown-value-using-express-in-node-js-from-html-page) is a good start, however when I enter console.log (req.body.choose) the script throws an error saying "Cannot read property 'choose' of undefined", or when I just console out req.body, the console returns "undefined", and I cannot seem to figure out why.

form:

```
<form action="./output.html" method = "post">
    <p>Table to Query</p>
    <select name="choose">
        <optgroup label="Table to Query">
            <option name="" value="0">Select table</option>
            <option name="Test1" value="octTest">table a</option>
            <option name="test2" value="donate">table b</option>
            <option name="test3" value="test2">table c</option>
        </optgroup>
        <input type="submit" />
    </select>
</form>
```

Node

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);//set port to localhost:3000

app.post('/query', function (req, res){ //retrieve & display webform
    console.log ("Incoming Request");
    res.type('text/html');
    res.send(formx);
    console.log("outgoing response");

    app.post('/output.html', function (req, res) {
        console.log(res.body.choose);
    });
});
```

Comment: In the code above, you've written `res.body.chooose` instead of `req.body.choose`. Does this fix the error?

Comment: no it does not. I think that was a typo when I copy and pasted it. I accidentally tacked on an extra "o". But thanks for telling me :D

Comment: @Duffman I think he was referring to the difference between `res` and `req`, rather than an extra `o`.

Comment: Whoops! Jamie Barker is right, I actually spelled `choose` as `chooose` by accident - the typo I was referring to was the difference between `res` and `req`, which is a very important distinction to make.

Comment: @JonathanBrooks, that actually did. I was looking in the wrong spot. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent! Update your post with the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The fix was in correcting the statement 
console.log (res.body.choose) to console.log(req.body.choose). Small typo, big difference.