# Simple dropdown sending the selected option back

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, express, https

I am simply trying to send the value of an option back to express/node and trying get a proper response here is my html:

```html
<p>Sign in</p>
<form action="/api/members/{{this.id}}" method="GET" class="mb-4">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class='form-field'>
         <select id='memberFilter' name='Users' class='form-control'>
            {{#each members}}
                 <option value="{{this.id}}">{{this.name}}</option>
             {{/each}}
         </select>
      </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
     </div>
</form>
```

And here is my router snippet:

```
// Get Single Member
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

  const found = members.some(idFilter(req));
if (found) {
    res.json(members.filter(idFilter(req)));
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: `No member with the id of ${req.params.id}` });
  }
});
```

I continue to have the call send:
http://www.localhost:8080/api/members/?Users=2
I can't seem to format the call properly as:
**http://www.localhost:8080/api/members/2**
which works.. anything would be helpful I am just learning express and node so please be kind.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe these answers will be useful to you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581459/get-dropdown-value-using-express-in-node-js-from-html-page